# Почему Qt Qreator не видит им же созданные файлы?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

В панели файлов я не вижу файлов и первоначальный стандартный проект не компилируется. Иду просто по начальным видео урокам, но не вижу файлов.
Чего может не хватать в нём?
Рядом с файлом FirstProj.pro QT Creator создал стандартные файлы .cpp .h  но их не видно и сборка тоже не собирается - пишет 
**Не удалось определить, какую команду «make» запускать. Проверьте шаг «make» в конфигурации сборки.**
Где это посмотреть можно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Спасибо

Comment: Проверьте, что в путях к файлу нет кириллических букв, qmake этого не любит. И покажите настройки сборки (tools -> options -> build and run, как в русскоязычном креаторе, не помню), возможно что-то неправильно настроено и/или неправильно определилось

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить компиляцию из консоли. Зайдите в папку с проектом, откройте консоль компилятора(Developer Command Prompt для студии или msys.bat для mingw), там пишите qmake, если ошибок не было пишите make. Если проект собрался, настраивайте креатор, если были ошибки выясняйте их причину

Comment: Совсем недавно столкнулся с такой же проблемой
После успешного написания программы для работы с измерительной аппаратурой и последующим успешной ее эксплуатацией возникла задача дописать имеющийся код.
И собственно компиляторы MSVC перестали определяться (не смог уловить момент, когда это произошло), если Вы успешно справились с данной проблемой сообщите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогла установка g++:

```
sudo apt install g++ -y
```